# Why is my bash script truncating passed-in argument?

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to pass in `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`, all as binary characters. When I print out `arg2`, it's truncating most of it. Here's a paste of the argument I'm passing in versus the result of me calling `echo` on `arg2` https://justpaste.it/57cyv

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
  key="$1"
  if [[ ! "$2" =~ ^-[^-].* ]];
    case $key in
      --arg1 | -t)
        arg1=$2
        shift #shift past argument
        ;;
      --arg2 | -k)
        arg2=$2
        shift #shift past argument
        ;;
      --arg3 | -i)
        arg3=$2
        break
        ;;
      *)
        #
        ;;
    esac
  fi
  shift
done
```

Comment: "binary characters"? There could be anything in there, including terminal control characters or carriage returns, maybe?

Comment: Shell variables are not suitable for arbitrary binary data, as they cannot store null bytes. All values in shell are null-terminated strings.

Comment: The link you posted shows a "space" in the argument after the last character of the result, which I suspect was a null byte.

Comment: as Benjamin and chepner have pointed out, you won't get very far trying to process arbitrary binary data with `bash`; if you provide more info about what you're trying to do then perhaps someone can suggest ideas on how to go about addressing your problem, eg, where did this binary string come from and what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: Note that it's not just the shell that isn't binary-safe -- unix-like OSes pass arguments as C strings, which are null-terminated and therefore by definition cannot contain null bytes. The shell (and its utilities) sometimes go further and expect strings to be valid UTF-8 or similar (depending on the locale environment variables).